# Drop down box selection fails to update in console

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple drop down box in my application. I need for every time a value is selected from the drop down box to update a text area with that value.

[Here is a JSFiddle to show what I mean.](https://jsfiddle.net/GeorgeBT/angoxs52/)

Although the text area on screen is updating with the value, if you use 'inspect element' on the JSFiddle you can see that the console never gets updated with the selected element.

Can any body explain why? And also how to correct this?

Many thanks,

```
`G`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log(...) line is not part of the anonymous function, move it inside the closing brace }.

```
var select = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
                    var input = document.getElementById('categoryChoice');
                    select.onchange = function() {
                        input.value = select.value;
                        console.log(input.value);
                    }
```

Comment: Silly me - That was a stupid one! I cant accept your answer for another 8 minutes but I will do after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var select = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
select.onchange = function() {
                    var input = document.getElementById('categoryChoice');
                        input.value = select.value;
                        console.log(input.value)
                    }
```